# Problema criando SLUG no codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olha só eu estou desenvolvendo o portal do meu selo musical, e estou tendo um problema bem chatinho.

Eu estou registrando as notícias, nomes de albums, nomes de artistas e por ai vai.

Quando registro no BD eu jogo em um campo o nome original do artista e no outro campo o nome para URL utilizando a função `url_title`.

O problema é que quando o nome do artista tem acentos especiais por exemplo: `á ê ô í ú à`, etc, ele salva o nome sem esse caractere, porém sem substituir por `a e o i u`, então o campo fica vazio e o nome incompleto, a URL não fica nada amigável.

Já tentei usar o `str_replace` porém não tive sucesso, ele substituiu os caracteres de formas erradas também.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz ou alguma solução?

Comment: Xim nes, tem como postar o código que já tem? assim fica mais fácil para quem for ajudar, já ter uma ideia do que você pretende fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver rapaziada.
[`convert_accented_characters()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html) é a função que não sabia que executa isso.

Abraços

Comment: Ótimo que conseguiu resolver, quando possível marque a sua resposta como aceita. =)

Comment: Recomendo concatenar seu slug gerado com um numero caso seu post se repita (caso esteja armazenado no banco de dados): ex `www.seusite.com/postagem/bolos-em-sao-paulo` `www.seusite.com/postagem/bolos-em-sao-paulo-2`

Comment: Valeu Mesmo a todos.E Jhonatan, eu to usando assim sim, só que essa sessão do site, seria nome de cds, então não teria um nome igual sacou? hehe

Answer (score -2):

Obrigado pelas dicas! Resolvi um problema do nosso tema com essa dica!
Troquei a linha 85 - $slug =  $premium['slug']; que sempre dava erro de "Illegal string offset 'version'" por $slug =  convert_accented_characters($premium['slug']); no arquivo: class/Util/ValidateLicense.php

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).